# svn changelists: how to limit operations to "default" changelist?

Tags: svn

Subversion 1.5 introduced changelists and I wanted to use this feature to group a change for later and continue to work on other files. The problem is that the subversion commands like `svn diff` and `svn commit` work on all modified files. I can limit the files they operate on if I specify a changelist with the `--changelist` option. But how can I limit the operations to files that are in no changelist at all?

For example: `file1` and `file2` are both modified. `file1` is in the changelist `A` and `file2` is in no changelist.

If I do `svn diff --changelist A` I see the diff for `file1`.

But if I do `svn diff` I see the diff for `file1` and `file2`.

How do I manage to see a diff of just `file2`, i.e. of all the files that are not part of a changelist?

I am using Subversion 1.6 (in case this makes a difference).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, subversion doesn't have a syntax to express that yet.

There are some ideas to allow a --changelist "" syntax, but that isn't implemented yet.

Comment: Seems that was reverted after you wrote that @rlovtang.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in doing this in a graphical environment, [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) (cross-platform) can do this for you.  Their free version is quite full-featured, too.

Comment: But then, so does tortoiseSVN

Comment: Actually, change sets are not available in free edition: http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/comparison.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by rlovtang a while back, [Subversion now does support more changelist options](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.changelist.html)

In special, the following command can be issued to commit only the files associated with a changelist:

```
svn changelist issue1729 foo.c bar.c baz.c
svn commit --changelist issue1729 -m "Fixing Issue 1729."
```